# How can I preg_match script tag src, but avoid effecting img tag src?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have to match local src's and make them load via the web. Example:

```
src="/js/my.js">
```

Becomes:

```
src="http://cdn.example.com/js/my.js">
```

This is what I have now:

```
if (!preg_match("#<script(.+?) src=\"http#i",$page)){ 
$page = preg_replace("#<script(.+?) src=\"#is", "<script$1 src=\"$workingUrl", $page); 
}
```

It works fine when it encounters something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
```

It fails when it encounters something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.moveTo(0,0);
window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height);
</script>
```

If the script tag doesn't contain a src it will then find the src of the first image tag and switch out its URL.

I need to know how to get it to terminate the match on the script tag only and/or how to perform the replacement better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php)

Comment: Any reason why you don't use `SimpleXML` or `DOMDocument`?

Comment: @Passerby Heard of non-valid HTML?

Comment: @BogdanBurim DOMDocument::loadHTML was created to attempt to make sense of non-wellformed HTML documents.

Comment: @Passerby DOMDocument::loadHTML may fail.  Well written regex - will never.

Comment: @BogdanBurim "Well written" is a no-fail phrase. And speaking of malformed, `<script dumb-data='made by dumb; src="/path/to"' src="...">` may either break your regex, or forces you to make complicate regex. Regex always mean what _itself_ means (by that it never fail), while `DOMDocument` will always mean what DOM means. But hey, programmer's choice, so pick whatever works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely use a DOM parser.  Xpath with DOMDocument will cleanly, reliably replace the script tags that:

1. Have a src attribute and
2. The src attribute does not start with http.

I could have further developed the xpath query expression to check for the leading `http` substring, but I didn't want to scare you off with more syntax.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rS0Ml))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
window.moveTo(0,0);
window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height);
</script>
</head>
</html>
HTML;

$workingUrl = 'https://www.example.com';

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//script[@src]") as $node) {
    if (strpos($node->getAttribute('src'), 'http') !== 0) {
        $node->setAttribute('src', $workingUrl);        
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
window.moveTo(0,0);
window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

---

The only slightly "scarier" xpath version: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ebpGj))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//script[@src and not(starts-with(@src,'http'))]") as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute('src', $workingUrl);        
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 2):

Barring the usage of DOMDocument::loadHTML and using the DOM instead, dropping the use of . and only accepting everything up to the first > as a fallback will probably work better (although not perfect, as there might in theoretical cases be other attributes to <script> that contain a >).

Using:

```
#<script([^>]+?) src=\"#is
```

as your pattern instead makes the pattern stop matching when it encounters the first > after <script.